# Router.refresh() not refreshing in next 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
'use client';

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Todo({ todo }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <>
            <li key={todo.id}>
                <input type='checkbox' checked={todo.isDone} onChange={(e) => update(todo.id, e.target.checked, router.refresh)}></input>
                {todo.name}
                <button onClick={() => todoDelete(todo.id, router)}>Delete</button>
            </li>
        </>
    )

    async function todoDelete(id, router) {
        await fetch(`/api/todo/delete?id=${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
    
        });
        router.refresh();
    }
    
}
```

The code seems to jump right over the refresh() function, but the rest of the API call is working fine. Anyone know why I'm unable to refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`router.refresh()` is meant for server-rendered components. It works by re-rendering the component on the server and sending back a fresh version with the updated data - thus it doesn't work on client-facing components because there is nothing rendered on the server (which is what you have here because of the 'use client' directive at the top)

From the Next 13 App Router beta [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/mutating):

> After a data mutation, you can use router.refresh() to refresh (fetch updated data and **re-render on the server**) the current route from the root layout down.

If you want to handle mutation on the client side, you have to manage the state and re-fetch the data yourself.

Comment: This works locally though

Comment: This is incorrect.  useRouter can only be used on client components, which is outlined in the docs you've linked.  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router

Answer (score 10):

I was having a similar issue. In my case, I did `router.refresh();` first followed by `router.push('/users')` to navigate back to the data table from the update page.

However, the correct implementation would be to do `router.push('/users')` first, followed by `router.refresh();`.

Comment: This resolved a different issue I had. But I cannot find any resource on this information about order of commands. Could you give me more information where you found this?

Answer (score 7):

Also as solution is using native reload page from JS

```
// Refresh the page
location.reload();
```

Comment: yeah... fuck it nextjs

Answer (score 5):

@adham. useRouter is react hook and can only be called on the client side

useRouter.refresh is https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router.

You're probably talking about useRouter from "next/router" which is not available in next13

Answer (score 0):

I would try not passing router as an argument into the todoDelete handler - it is unusual and unnecessery since variable router is defined in the same scope as todoDelete . I know that technically this should not affect the order of execution yet I would try, because your snippet should work as it is with no extra hacks. Even if you were using todoDelete in different component and passing it into it as a prop you would still not pass router as an argument there but import useRouter in that other component. So perhaps that causes some unexpected behaviour